# how to access a website using Apache from internet using no-ip?

Tags: apache, wamp, router, nat, dyndns

**CREATE ACCOUNT IN no-ip.com**

hostname: softparapymes.no-ip.org

download the DUC v4.0.2 and install

**CONFIGURATION OF THE ROUTER**

ELTEL Group,

Model: ET-5300

opening the port 80

[image]

**CONFIGURATION OF THE WAMP SERVER**

*The file phpmyadmin.conf*

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 190.87.185.218
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from softparapymes.no-ip.org
</Directory>
```

**I configured this, but I displays the router's settings and not my website. What am I doing wrong or I need to configure?**

Comment: Make sure you have the latest Firmware installed on the router, make sure there is no distinction between TCP and UDP. Did you try to restart the router? What you need is the menupoint **NAT**, not sure if this is the same as *virtual server*. Also, when accessing the website, make sure to use the external address (http://softparapymes.no-ip.org/) not the local one.

Comment: yes I've tried but has not worked yet. some settings I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

On my router, I had to find an Advanced DMZ hosting area and select one of my machines by mac address, and then I could access it from within my network, by going to my routers IP (not the NAT).  Whereas the regular DMZ hosting option, my routers IP would take me to the configuration page for the router.  Not sure with your specific setup, but this would be something to look for.  Alternatively, call support for your router?

Comment: In the DMZ I have configured my server ip.

Comment: Look for Advanced DMZ.  You might not have it but if you do that's where you need to allow the local machine to be visible to the outside world.  Before I was using regular DMZ as well and had the same problem, but then I found advanced DMZ and I can see my website when I go to my outside ip, rather than my nat ip of the local server machine.  Maybe your router doesn't support it.  I use ActionTek.

Comment: then my router would not serve me to do what I need or could install something so you can offer this service

Comment: @IAteYourKitten NEVER EVER put a PC in the DMZ unless you really know what you are doing and are doing it for the right reasons. Running a webserver is definitely not the right reason.

Answer (score 0):

**I have to say this first**

1. NEVER EVER put a PC in the DMZ unless you really know what you are
   doing!
2. Are you really sure you want to give access to your phpmyadmin
   to the world?

**If you are sure** about giving phpmyadmin access to the world, make sure that you are using very strong passwords. I would also suggest creating a new SuperUser account with a non obvious username and a very strong password and then deleting the `root` user. The whole world knows about the `root` username on a MySQL server. At least if you change it to something else hackers will have to guess the account name as well as the password. (So dont use 'admin' as the account name either).

It looks like you have configured your router correctly.

This configuration is enough to open phpmyadmin up to the world. `Allow from all` does exactly what it says, it allows any ip address to connect to this Directory so all the other stuff is just noise and possible confusion.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Oh and if you are using Apache 2.4.x the syntax has changed a little, although both versions of the syntax should work as long as you have the apache module modules/mod_access_compat.so loaded.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The normal problem with testing that you can access the site or phpmyadmin in your case is that most home/office routers do not have the required feature ( loopback ) either installed or turned on to allow the router to see that you are inside your local network when you use the url `softparapymes.no-ip.org` and loop you back inside the local network.

So to test your configuration use a device/PC outside your home/office network, and it will probably work.

Comment: Thank You very much for your reply , i will try to access from another network to see if it works